# Show a 404 for not-found subdomains instead of showing root domain's content

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I'm using nginx. What I'm trying to achieve:

- A root domain `domain.com` which gets contents from `/var/www/domain.com`
- A subdomain `sub.domain.com` which gets contents from `/var/www/sub.domain.com`
- Any *other* subdomain `*.domain.com` (where `*` != `sub`) should get contents from `/var/www/404`

<sup>If this isn't clear: it is similar to the StackEchange setup, where http://somesub.stackexchange.com/ gives a 404.</sup>

I succeed in the first using two server blocks with different `server_name`s. However, how can I setup nginx to link to `/var/www/404` when no server block matching the subdomain is found?

With a basic setup, all subdomains that are not found return the same contents as the root domain.

I'd like to make this generic, so that if I add another server block for `sub2.domain.com`, I don't have to change the block for the 404.

The code I'm using now:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    root /var/www/domain.com;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html;
        autoindex on;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include         fastcgi_params;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.domain.com;
    root /var/www/sub.domain.com;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html;
        autoindex on;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include         fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nginx, like Apache, will always use its first domain in the config list as its default. In your case, that means that for any domain that doesn't have its own config, it will choose the config for domain.com as that is the first one.

So the solution is simply to set up another domain that contains only a 404 page, and have that be the first domain listed. You can then add as many specific domains as you like; the first one will only be used when there's no other matching domain name in the config file.